# Standardizing odds ratios with opposite outcomes for lit review

Tags: odds-ratio, systematic-review

When doing a lit review, I find that results are frequently presented in different ways. Sometimes the outcome is Facility Births (FB), sometimes it is Home Births (HB). These are dichotomous outcomes.  I'd like to be able to convert them all to make Facility Births the outcome so they are easier to compare, but I don't know if this is possible.

I know that I can convert OR< 1 to OR >1 by using the equation 1/x, where x=OR<1, which then reverses the factors being compared. For example,

FB is less likely than HB in rural [OR=.26 (.12, .50)] than urban areas

converts to:
FB is more likely than HB in urban [OR=3.85 (2.00, 8.33] vs rural areas

My question is how to convert:
HB is more likely than FB in rural [OR=22.8 (10.6, 49.4)] than urban areas

Is it correct to say:
FB is more likely than HB in urban [OR=22.8 (10.6, 49.4)] than rural areas

Or is there some calculation that needs to be done?

Comment: There's a disconnect here: you appear to be asking to convert a statement about "FB" into one about "HB".  Could there by some (critical) typographical errors?

Comment: No, that is correct. Sometimes results are reported in terms of FB, sometimes in terms of HB. These are dichotomous outcomes. I want to be able to report them in terms of FB, as this is my outcome of interest.

Comment: What are they?  All you have said is that they are "outcomes."  How are they related?

Comment: I have edited my question to hopefully make it clearer. Facility Births and Home Births are dichotomous outcomes.

Comment: I believe a clearer term might be "complementary values of a single dichotomous variable."

Answer (score 1):

When you reverse one factor you take the reciprocal, as you suggest. When you reverse the other you take the reciprocal again and so end up where you started from.